# How do I prevent Graphics.DrawImage from scaling the picture?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013

I am using a code that creates an image tooltip when the user hovers over the button. However, for some reason, for some of the buttons, the image gets scaled larger and doesnt completely fit in the tooltip window. I have no idea why some images are getting scaled and not others. Here is the code:

```
Protected Overrides Sub OnLoad(e As EventArgs)
    MyBase.OnLoad(e)
    ToolTip1.OwnerDraw = True
    For Each ctrl As Control In Controls
        If TypeOf ctrl Is Button Then
            ToolTip1.SetToolTip(ctrl, " ")
        End If
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub ToolTip1_Popup(sender As Object, e As PopupEventArgs) Handles ToolTip1.Popup
    Dim oTemplate As String = e.AssociatedControl.Name
    Dim ButtonPic As Image = Image.FromFile(System.IO.Path.GetFullPath("TemplatesResources\MouseHoverPics\" & oTemplate & ".png"))
    e.ToolTipSize = New Size(ButtonPic.Size.Width, ButtonPic.Size.Height)
End Sub

Private Sub ToolTip1_Draw(sender As Object, e As DrawToolTipEventArgs) Handles ToolTip1.Draw
    Dim oTemplate As String = e.AssociatedControl.Name
    Dim ButtonPic As Image = Image.FromFile(System.IO.Path.GetFullPath("TemplatesResources\MouseHoverPics\" & oTemplate & ".png"))
    e.Graphics.Clear(SystemColors.Info)
    e.Graphics.DrawImage(ButtonPic, New System.Drawing.Point(0, 0))
End Sub
```

The results:

Looking good at first.
[image: Looks good!]

Scaling begins....
[image: Uh Oh!]

Even more scaling the further right I go... could it possibly have to do with the button placement? I cant see why the code would take that into consideration
[image: What...]

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: you need to use the `DrawImage` overload that specifies the destination bounds of the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That happens because when you call

- e.ToolTipSize = New Size(ButtonPic.Size.Width, ButtonPic.Size.Height)

you set [size of the popup = size of the image]. But what happens if you don't have enough space between your mouse cursor and the border of the window? The popup resize itself, and when you load the image inside of it, the image scale itself to match the current width/height

- e.Bounds()

So all you have to do is to check the Bounds of the popup and scale manteining the ratio before call DrawImage() method.

Here's and example

```
Private Sub ToolTip1_Draw(sender As Object, e As DrawToolTipEventArgs) Handles ToolTip1.Draw
    Dim oTemplate As String = e.AssociatedControl.Name
    Dim ButtonPic As Image = Image.FromFile(System.IO.Path.GetFullPath("TemplatesResources\MouseHoverPics\" & oTemplate & ".png"))
    e.Graphics.Clear(SystemColors.Info)
    If ButtonPic.Width > e.Bounds.Widht Or ButtonPic.Height > e.Bounds.Height Then
        [code to rescale, make it as you prefer]
    End If
    e.Graphics.DrawImage(ButtonPic, New System.Drawing.Point(0, 0))
End Sub
```

Comment: There are some typo, sorry

Comment: Curious how I would rescale it. Its not letting me change the ButtonPic.Size.Width properties because "expression is a value and cannot be the target of an assignment". And I am not sure how to do a scale transform. Looking at the image class, I cant find any properties that can be set besides palette and tags,

Comment: Yes, you can't directly change ButtonPic.Size Width&Height because there are readonly values.

By default there's no way to resize an image with the System method/function.. you have to define your personal resize function or import a library that manipulates images.
If you're searching for a library i suggest Itextsharp.
If you want to define your own resize method here's a simple tutorial: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/191424/Resizing-an-Image-On-The-Fly-using-NET

Comment: I got it using the article you linked! Thanks!